# Clash of Clans API PHP with nested JSON issues

Tags: php, json

I am having issues with my PHP loading. I am using PHP to call on the Clash of Clans API JSON. Here is the location I am going for in the JSON: "clan" > "members" > "bestOpponentAttack"

```
{"clan": {
    "destructionPercentage": {},
    "tag": "string",
    "name": "string",
    "badgeUrls": {},
    "clanLevel": 0,
    "attacks": 0,
    "stars": 0,
    "expEarned": 0,
    "members": [
      {
        "tag": "string",
        "name": "string",
        "mapPosition": 0,
        "townhallLevel": 0,
        "opponentAttacks": 0,
        "bestOpponentAttack": {
          "order": 0,
          "attackerTag": "string",
          "defenderTag": "string",
          "stars": 0,
          "destructionPercentage": 0
        },
        "attacks": [
          {
            "order": 0,
            "attackerTag": "string",
            "defenderTag": "string",
            "stars": 0,
            "destructionPercentage": 0
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "teamSize": 0,
  "opponent": {
    "destructionPercentage": {},
    "tag": "string",
    "name": "string",
    "badgeUrls": {},
    "clanLevel": 0,
    "attacks": 0,
    "stars": 0,
    "expEarned": 0,
    "members": [
      {
        "tag": "string",
        "name": "string",
        "mapPosition": 0,
        "townhallLevel": 0,
        "opponentAttacks": 0,
        "bestOpponentAttack": {
          "order": 0,
          "attackerTag": "string",
          "defenderTag": "string",
          "stars": 0,
          "destructionPercentage": 0
        },
        "attacks": [
          {
            "order": 0,
            "attackerTag": "string",
            "defenderTag": "string",
            "stars": 0,
            "destructionPercentage": 0
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "startTime": "string",
  "state": "string",
  "endTime": "string",
  "preparationStartTime": "string"
}
```

Here is my PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
<?php
$clantag = "<CLAN OMITTED>";

$token = 

"<TOKEN OMITTED>";

$url = "https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/clans/" . urlencode($clantag) . "/currentwar";

$ch = curl_init($url);

$headr = array();
$headr[] = "Accept: application/json";
$headr[] = "Authorization: Bearer ".$token;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headr);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

$res = curl_exec($ch);
$data = json_decode($res, true);
curl_close($ch);

if (isset($data["reason"])) {
  $errormsg = true;
}

$members = $data["clan"]["members"];

?>
  <title><?php echo $data["clan"]["name"]; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
  if (isset($errormsg)) {
    echo "<p>", "Failed: ", $data["reason"], " : ", isset($data["message"]) ? $data["message"] : "", "</p></body></html>";
    exit;
  }
?>

  <table border="1">

    <tr>

      <td>Map Position</td>
      <td>Tag</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>TH lvl</td>
      <td>Opponent Attacks</td>
      <td>Best Opponent Attack</td>

    </tr>

    <?php
      foreach ($members as $member) {
    ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $member["mapPosition"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $member["tag"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $member["name"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $member["townhallLevel"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $member["opponentAttacks"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $member["bestOpponentAttack"]; ?></td>

        </tr>
    <?php
      }
    ?>

  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Everything like 'tag','name','mapPosition','townhallLevel','opponentAttacks' display just fine. When I add "bestOpponentAttack" I got this error:

"Notice: Undefined index: bestOpponentAttack in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 68"

I don't know what I am doing wrong, been working on this for a couple days and can't figure out why my nested JSON is coming back as undefined.

Comment: Well, bestOpponentAttack is going to be an assoc array and you cannot each that, but you would see a different error.  Try echo print_r($member["bestOpponentAttack"], true); instead of echo $member["bestOpponentAttack"];

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is what my new line looks like

<td><?php echo print_r($member["bestOpponentAttack], true); ?></td>

I am still getting the no index error. Should I be trying to use another part of the JSON. I guess how do I go into that nested part if it can't be eached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so all Arrays in PHP are iterable; you can absolutely foreach `bestOpponentAttack`:

```
php > var_dump($bestOpponentAttack);
array(5) {
  ["order"]=>
  int(1)
  ["attackerTag"]=>
  string(3) "abc"
  ["defenderTag"]=>
  string(3) "def"
  ["stars"]=>
  int(3)
  ["destructionPercentage"]=>
  int(100)
}
php > foreach ($bestOpponentAttack as $key=>$value){echo "{$key} : {$value}\n";}
order : 1
attackerTag : abc
defenderTag : def
stars : 3
destructionPercentage : 100
```

I guess the first question is do you know for sure that `bestOpponentAttack` is *always* present in the JSON?

If so, the next problem is that `$members[0]['bestOpponentAttack']` is an Array, which you're trying to pass to `echo`, which only takes Strings as arguments. But it raises the larger point that the information you want is inside `$members[0]['bestOpponentAttack']`, not `$members[0]['bestOpponentAttack']` itself:

```
["members"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(7) {
        ["tag"]=>
        string(6) "string"
        ["name"]=>
        string(6) "string"
        ["mapPosition"]=>
        int(0)
        ["townhallLevel"]=>
        int(0)
        ["opponentAttacks"]=>
        int(0)
        ["bestOpponentAttack"]=>
        array(5) {
          ["order"]=>
          int(0)
          ["attackerTag"]=>
          string(6) "string"
          ["defenderTag"]=>
          string(6) "string"
          ["stars"]=>
          int(0)
          ["destructionPercentage"]=>
          int(0)
        }...
```

You've consigned the entire Array to a single table cell but you need to decide how you want to present each piece of that Array's information within the cell itself, then access each piece appropriately. You can iterate through it if you want, or directly access the data you want in that cell (e.g. `$members[0]['bestOpponentAttack']['order']`).

Comment: That's right I want what's in bestOpponentAttack. It isn't always present, but it is right now, and I am trying to call $data["clan"]["members"]["bestOpponentAttack"]["destructionPercentage"]. I am just taking the title of each next indented nest in the list of raw output, but as I go into ["bestOpponentAttack"] it doesn't recognize that it exists. ["destructionPercentage"] is an int 0 to 100.

Comment: Here is another example, I get this error: "Notice: Undefined index: bestOpponentAttack in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 128" and line 128 is "<td><?php echo $member["bestOpponentAttack"]["destructionPercentage"]; ?></td>" where the end of the line is pointing to an int, so echo should be able to print it out right?

Comment: Okay, last comment I swear :3 I figured out that I was skipping from bestopponentattack to destructionpercentage, when I needed to call the right array in between those two. A working fix for the attacks is changing line 128 to "<td><?php echo $member["attacks"][0]["destructionPercentage"]; ?></td>" instead of having it without a '[0]'.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. That code wasn't meant to be a literal solution to your issue, just an example based on the example `$members` array given in the answer. Also if there's no promise that JSON fields are going to be present, it would be most prudent to check for their existence explicitly in your code before attempting to act upon them.

Comment: Yea, thinking of them as arrays, and then doing a raw dump of the JSON helped break it down. The last thing you said helped the most since I didn't know you could call an array with something like a '[0]'.